# Difference between Relation and term reference field

Tags: entities

Can anyone explain, what is the difference from practice point of view between relation (by Relation module) and term reference?

I mean if I will use as product attribute taxonomy term, what type of attribute connection I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you should use https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference

This one is lighter and does the job without overcomplicating. It simply stores 1 to n relations, which may be used later to display in Views.

Relation - this module is much more advanced and allows you to make:

1. directional references, example

   - user A is "boss" of user B
2. different types of references between same entities, example:

   - reference type 1:  user C is "friend" of user D

     AND
   - reference type 2:  user C "follows" user D
3. these references are entities itself, so they are fieldable, could be displayed in Views separately etc.

Comment: But what is the difference between Entity reference and for example Term reference. I can use taxonomy to mark content as I want, so what will be advantages of using entity reference?

Comment: Entity reference is succesor of Term reference. From functionality point of view it does the same, because every Taxonomy Term is an Entity as well. Howewer Enity Reference is now supported and will let you set another types of references in case you need some in the future.